# Issues with a LinkButton not fireing when turning OFF compatility view IE11

Tags: css, asp.net, linkbutton, asprepeater

I built a.net Web Application with the compatibility view activated on IE without knowing. Deactivating the compatibility view not just makes everything look like crap, but also cuts the functionality of a LinkButton that is not firing the event.

I'm building a calendar by populating a repeater in a sequential way. The Data comes from a SQL.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" id="RepeaterCalendar">
<ItemTemplate>

<asp:label ID="Month_lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Month") %>'/>
<asp:label ID="Pretag_lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PRETAG") %>'/>
<asp:LinkButton ID="ButtonSelect" runat="server" CommandName ="Select" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("date") %>' Text='<%# Bind("TAG") %>'  style="vertical-align:text-bottom" OnClick="GetDetails" Visible="true"  /> 
<asp:label ID="Posttag_lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("POSTTAG") %>'/>
<asp:label ID="Monthend_lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MonthEnd") %>'/>

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

With Compatibility view turned off the LinkButton doesn't fire the event, while it does work perfectly when switching Compatibility view on again.

---

I guess it has to do with all the fractured code bits that I glue together to form the calendar table using the asp:repeater. If I bind a "normal" column without any html tags, then the LinkButton works as expected; but this ruins the whole calendar design.

Martin

Answer (score 2):

```html
<asp:Repeater runat="server" id="RepeaterCalendar">
<ItemTemplate>

<asp:label ID="Month_lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Month") %>'/>
<asp:label ID="Pretag_lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PRETAG") %>'/>
<asp:LinkButton ID="ButtonSelect" runat="server" CommandName ="Select"
                CausesValidation="false" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("date") %>' Text='<%# Bind("TAG") %>'  style="vertical-align:text-bottom" OnClick="GetDetails" Visible="true"  /> 
<asp:label ID="Posttag_lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("POSTTAG") %>'/>
<asp:label ID="Monthend_lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MonthEnd") %>'/>

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Use CausesValidation="false"

Comment: Cool! That did it. Thank you, Martin

Comment: I must have been confused or switched back to compatibility view without being aware of it. But CausesValidation="false" doesn't have an impact on it. Sorry.